# How do I install ArangoDB on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS 32-bit

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, arangodb

I followed the instructions found here: https://www.arangodb.com/download-major/ubuntu/ under the "Packages for Ubuntu 12.04:" section and when I got to the line:
sudo apt-get install arangodb3=3.1.19
I received the following error:
"Unable to locate package arangodb3"

Comment: The source link for that program is not in the package list ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArangoDB does not provide any official 32-bit builds ([source](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/2334#issuecomment-282758457)).
If you **really** need to install it on that system, you can try to follow the instructions provided in the [cookbook](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/cookbook/Compiling/) to compile it manually.